# how to find where template variable is coming from in meteor.js

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor

In someone elses meteor app code they have some thing like the following:

```
<template name="null">
   {{>main}}
</template>

<template name="main">
    {{#if some_user}}
       text or whatever
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

But no where in their client code do they have a Template.null and they define only one helper for main e.g.

```
Template.main.mode
   return Session.get('mode')
```

some_user does exist but I can't figure out where it is coming from. I searched through all the projects files and currentUser is only defined in the template so I assume its the property of some object that is returned. What is the best way to figure out where it is coming from?

Comment: It looks a bit like a placeholder for something you could put in. Is the source for the app online? Could you put the link up

Comment: sorry it was something I found on madewithmeteor, I just went back and it looks like the repo was taken down or deleted. I'd give you the credit for the question if you could answer where the Meteor.subscribe happens for core modules like accounts (we automagically get the user subscription when accounts is added but how/where does this happen?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a package that is installed. Simply search the entire codebase including the directories under the .meteor folder for all calls to publish and you'll find it.

Answer (score 0):

If the `some_user` helper is not defined anywhere in the code, then it's stub (incomplete) code.

To answer your other question about subscribe for core modules. If you have the default autopublish package installed, then the entire database is published including the user database. If you remove the autopublish package, then you'll only be able to see the user information for the logged in user. Unless you publish and subscribe to it.

I've been building a new app with Meteor for about a month. So I'm no where near an expert, but I hope this helps. Good luck!